# Value of dropdown should be thrown, must not accept select value

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, dropdown

I want validate my dropdown but my code is not working, it still output the select value. This is my front-end code. Can you help me thanks! Do i need to add code behind this ones?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtAlbumVersion" runat="server" ValidationGroup="g1" 
                         AppendDataBoundItems ="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Korean</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Chinese</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Japanese</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Korean and Chinese</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Display="Dynamic" 
            ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAlbumVersion"
            Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please choose version!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2021?

Comment: Where does is `output the select value`? Are trying to access selected value in code behind? In a click event of a button? Can you share that code?

Comment: Could be a host of issues.  Are you validating the ValidationGroup g1?  Is your submit being done by a form submission, or is it being intercepted by javascript and submitted via ajax?  Is the validation javascript being loaded into the page?  Are the controls inside an asp.net form control?

Comment: I already solved my problem on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for meeeee. :)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtAlbumVersion" runat="server"
                         AppendDataBoundItems ="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Korean</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Chinese</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Japanese</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Korean and Chinese</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Display="Dynamic" 
             runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAlbumVersion" ErrorMessage="Please choose version!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```